# I have a code in which i want to display my data in the content using there ids stored in database

Tags: php

I m developing a website and here is my code, in my code i have two ids `sId` (section) and `ssId` (SubSectionId) and i have a page lets say `index.php` now I am making url like this -- when i click on the left navigation bar where i have links AND when i click on one link it sends an id like `localhost/index.php?sId=29&ssId=0`

Now i want to show `ssId=181` data on the same page `index.php` using there ids by taping the same leftnav of the subsection which sends an id `localhost/index.php?sId=29&ssId=181`

The issue here is that the result is showing on the contentarea of `sId=29` instead of `ssId=181` and both are stored in database..

```
if(isset($_GET['sId']) && !empty($_GET['sId']))
{
?>
   <div>
    <br /><br />
        <h2 class="heading">
        <?php 
           $sId = intval($_GET['sId']);
           $qry = "SELECT `SectionId`,`Title`,`Details` FROM `section` WHERE `SectionId` = $sId";
           $records = mysql_query($qry);
           while($record= mysql_fetch_array($records))
           {
              echo $record['Title'];    
          ?>
        </h2>
        <br />
        <p>
        <?php
              echo $record['Details'];
           }
        ?>  
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
}
elseif(isset($_GET['sId']) && !empty($_GET['sId']) && isset($_GET['ssId']) && !empty($_GET['ssId']))
{
?>      
 <div>
 <br /><br />
 <h2 class="heading">
 <?php 
     $sId = intval($_GET['sId']);
     $ssId = intval($_GET['ssId']); 
     $qry = "SELECT SubSectionId,Title,Details FROM `pages` WHERE `SubSectionId` = $ssId";
     $records = mysql_query($qry);
     while($record= mysql_fetch_array($records))
     {
        echo $record['Title'];
     ?> 
        </h2>
        <br />
        <p>
     <?php 
        echo $record['Details'];
     }
     ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>      
<?php   
  }
}
```

Hope you guys understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're saying the following.

1. Your script expects an sid and/or and ssid as input.
2. If either is supplied, your script will load the relevant content from the DB and show it
3. But, currently your script does not show content of the ssid and will only show the content of the sid

Am I right?

Try using two IF blocks rather than an IF/ELSE. This will make sure that all conditions that are met will be run rather than just one.

Also, you can stick to using the just the `empty` function call.

```
if ( !empty($_GET['sId']) ) {
   //load and show content for section
}

if ( !empty($_GET['ssId']) ) {
   //load and show content for sub section
}
```

**UPDATE** - To give subsections precedence over sections, you'll need to reverse your IF/ELSE condition.

```
if ( !empty($_GET['sId']) && !empty($_GET['ssId']) ) {
   //load and show content for sub section if availavle

} else if ( !empty($_GET['sId']) ) {

   //load and show content for section
}
```

Comment: yes john exactly what I want but problem is that i have used elseif condition to show the result of subsections if sId=29&ssId=181 but its not showing me the result.

Comment: If a subsection is defined, do you only want to show the subsection and not the main? If that is the case, you need to reverse the order of your IF/ELSE so that the sub section condition is checked first.

Comment: yes i want to show subsections details in the content area when i tap on the one leftnav link it sends an id to the url and then i getting this id and giving to the query which have to show me result stored in that id on the content area that's all i want.

Comment: `if ( !empty($_GET['sId'])) 
{
   // if this condition true i want to display its data here
} else if ( !empty($_GET['ssId']) ) {
   // if this condition true i want to display its data here means same page but want to overlap ssId over sId data
}`

Comment: If you want to show both section and subsection data, then use the first method of having 2 IF conditions. If this isn't what you're asking for, I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: I have used both the methods but first method showing me sId data then showing ssId data below the details/data of sId means two data on one page.. well thanks anyways i think m bothering you

Comment: @SalmanWebDeveloper You aren't bothering me, but you might want to update your question with more details. Maybe an example of what you want it to look like so I can help you.

Comment: Thanks i solved my problem actually i was putting if conditions in the same block.. well thanks a lot @JohnP :-)